# Solving $xy''-y'+4x^3y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to solve

$$xy''-y'+4x^3y=0$$

by reduction or order, knowing one solution is $y=\sin x^2$. That's what I did:

$y_2 = v(x)\sin x^2\implies \\y_2' = v'\sin x^2+2xv\cos x^2\implies\\y_2'' = v''\sin x^2+2xv'\cos x^2+2(-2vx^2\sin x^2+v'x\cos x^2+v\cos x^2)$

Then,

$$xy_2''-y_2'+4x^3y_2 = \\xv''\sin x^2+2x^2v'\cos x^2-4vx^3\sin x^2+2x^2v'\cos x^2+2xv\cos x^2-v'\sin x^2-2vx\cos x^2+4x^3v\sin x^2 = \\$$
$$xv''\sin x^2+4v'x^2\cos x^2-v'\sin x^2$$

which seems like a difficult equation to solve, so I guess it's wrong. Also, [wolfram alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xv%27%27sin(x%5E2)%2B4v%27x%5E2cos(x%5E2)-v%27sin(x%C2%B2)) the solution for $v$ is $c_1\cot x^2+c_2$, but my book says that $y_2$ is $\cos x^2$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @moo omg yes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=\sin x^2 \int v(x) dx $

$y' =2x \cos x^2 \int v(x) dx +v(x)\sin x^2 $

$y''=2\cos x^2 \int v(x) dx -4x^2 \sin x^2 \int v(x) dx +2x v(x)\cos x^2 +v'(x)\sin x^2 +2xv(x) \cos x^2 $

so

$xy'' -y' +4x^3 y =x\left(2\cos x^2 \int v(x) dx -4x^2 \sin x^2 \int v(x) dx +2x v(x)\cos x^2 +v'(x)\sin x^2 +2xv(x) \cos x^2\right) - \left(2x \cos x^2 \int v(x) dx +v(x)\sin x^2\right) +4x^3 \sin x^2 \int v(x) dx =4x^2 v(x)\cos x^2 +xv'(x) \sin x^2 -v(x) \sin x^2$

hence

$\frac{v'}{v} =\frac{1}{x} +4x\cot x^2 $

thus

$\ln v = \ln x +2\ln |\sin x^2 |+ \ln C$